# ';' expected while i follow tutorial

Tags: java, class, ioexception

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     throw IOException{

        }
    }
}
```

Can some body help me please i follow tutorial but it show up ';' expected error

Comment: I think you wanted `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{` (Emphasis on throw*s*.)

Comment: I suggest you go back to your tutorial and make sure you copied the code correctly.

Comment: throw is an action, you need a ; using the through, place it after IOException, you don't need the scope parentheses there.

Comment: On the method signature, it is "throw**s**". Within a method, you can do things like `throw new IOException("some message")`. Yes, details, such as a trailing "s" matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont't want to throw exception by using a try catch the second Methode is to do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  //But your Code here where you Need to throw an Exception
}
```

The second Methode is to use a try/catch

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  try{

    //Code which throws an exception
  }catch(IOException e){
     e.printstacktrace();
  }

}
```

Comment: How THIS answer differs from MINE?

Comment: you dont Need the `throw new IOException();`

Comment: @Nikolas and you didn't tell him that there is a second way to do it by the `try/catch`